# Should I inline this in c++?

Tags: c++, optimization

I am not sure if I should inline this:

```
float bm_softlight (float a, float b) {
    float Da = (a > 0.25f) ? sqrt (a) : ((16*a - 12) * a + 4) * a;
    return (b > 0.5f) ? Da*(2*b - 1) + 2*a*(1-b) : 2*a*b + a*a*(1-2*b);
}
```

Is it simple enough function that can and should be inlined?

Thanks

Comment: The compiler can probably figure out if it should be inlined without your help.

Comment: What Seth said.  it  depends on the number of times and places the function is called -- basically a space/time tradeoff.  The time-saving is itslef dependent on the processor and compiler's call/return overhead.   A good compiler can remove stack frames and pass values in and out of functions using registers directly,  making function calls very efficient.  But as a matter of habit, I tend to provide an `inline` hint to small functions such as these.

Comment: A side note. Either you decide it on your own whether to hint the compiler with `inline` or trust the compiler with the decision, you should place the function's definition into a header, not .cpp, to simply allow the function to be inlined (unless your are familiar with such fancy things as LTCG and LTO).

Comment: I'm not expert on this but according to me if you use this function frequently, declaring that inline makes no harm to your program since it is a simple one.

Comment: @emreakyilmaz: if you use this function frequently, as in, you call it a lot in different places, this leads to code duplication, which will not be trivial, because the function is not simple at all (a lot of calculations). This code duplication increases your size and the likeliness of cache misses.

Answer (score 4):

There is no concrete answer when to inline. `Inline` is just a hint to compiler. So it may ignore it or it may inline without the hint.

In case of inlining performance may both increase and decrease. One of the reasons performance may decrease is that inlining increases the side of the code and it may become less cache friendly. You should try your code with and without `inline` to say if it works.

And don't optimize until you find the bottleneck

Answer (score 3):

Due to optimization modern compilers make, the use of `inline` is not that obvious and transparent. Sometimes a compiler will automaticaly make a small function inline even if it's not declared so. On the other hand, sometimes it will not make a function inline even if you declare it to be so.

You can't realy tell that because you can't tell what is less costy: a function call, or duplicating the code (well you can, maybe, but that isn't easy to do at a glance). The compiler, on the other hand, manages it pretty well.

Also, remember a famous quote of Donald Knuth:

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of
>   it) in programming.

Comment: Bjarne Stroustrup: There is no root of all evil in programming.

Comment: @KillianDS Just what Stroustrup said.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `sqrt` and conditionals will take much more than the extra call. Regardless, `inline` is just a hint.

If you want to separate the implementation to a source file, it makes no difference whether you specify `inline` or not.

If you keep the definition in a header, you **must** declare the function as `inline` to prevent multiple definitions. This is not to say the function will actually be inlined.